# How can i create custom ui for stripe payment getaway for ios

Tags: swift, xcode, stripe-payments

Now i have task to integrate stripe payment getaway for ios app, and this is first time use stripe.My problem is how can make custom UI design payment getaway like in the picture. I have read documentation show me how can i handle colors of the standard ui but didn’t show how can create my own design. and also how can i handle information of the payment will the user fill it to the custom Ui text fields . If anyone has done this before if he could help me i will be grateful. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe provides low-level APIs that you can use to build your own UI elements on top of: https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPAPIClient.html

You can find more info in the Github repo for stripe-ios: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios#features

Comment: Thank you  you have saved my day

Comment: I have question about security perspective, it’s better to use   default payment ui for security like documentation said.  

Simplified Security: We make it simple for you to collect sensitive data such as credit card numbers and remain PCI compliant. This means the sensitive data is sent directly to Stripe instead of passing through your server. For more information, see our Integration Security Guide.